# Lilypond displays chords over every bar

Tags: lilypond

According to Lilypond's documentation, you can choose to only have chords displayed when they change. I cannot get this behaviour. Here is the snippet:

```latex
\new ChordNames  {
        \chordmode {
            d1:7 d1:7 
        }
  }
```

Here is the alternate snippet:

```latex
\new ChordNames  {
        \chordmode {
            d1:7 d:7 
        }
  }
```

In both cases Lilypond displays the chord names above both bars. This is the same throughout the score. I cannot get it to not display repeat chord names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\set chordChanges = ##t`. Try this snippet:

```
\new ChordNames  {
    \chordmode {
        \set chordChanges = ##t
        d1:7 d1:7 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of you. I think the example given in the documentation was unnecessarily complex, with the use of a variable. Since I wasn't using a variable I didn't copy that part of the snippet and that was my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1753389, as a good StackOverflow citizen, please be sure to accept the answer that helped you the most. Thanks!

Comment: @Owen S. -- how do I do that? Not sure what you mean by "accept the answer".

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you've missed to set `chordChanges` to `true`. The [example in the LilyPond docs is](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-chords#index-chords_002c-suppressing-repeated):

```tex
1    harmonies = \chordmode {
2      c1:m c:m \break c:m c:m d
3    }
4    <<
5      \new ChordNames {
6        \set chordChanges = ##t
7        \harmonies
8      }
9      \new Staff {
10        \relative c' { \harmonies }
11     }
12   >>
```

In this example, line 6 is essential to display chords only on chord changes:

> `\set chordChanges = ##t`

So, you need to add this command to your lilypond source code.